# Return text if tablix results are empty

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a tablix that is linked to DataSet1.

DataSet1 uses the following TSQL code

```
select ir.SourceRef as Account_Ref,
       rab.BalanceFromDate,
       rab.ClosingBalance Current_Balance,
       ra.Account_ID as rserial,
       ra.Current_Balance as Current_Balance


from db1..RentAccountBalance rab
left join db1..ImportReference ir on ir.EntityID = rab.AccountId and ir.EntityType='XXXX.XXX.X.XX'
left join db2..RentAccounts ra on convert(varchar(50),ra.Account_ID) = ir.SourceRef

where ir.SourceRef = '12857'
order by rab.AccountBalanceId
```

As I know that there is no ir.SourceRef that is equal to 12857, the result set is blank. Therefore, my tablix comes back just blank.Is there a way that if no results are returned that a text of say "All Accounts are OK." be displayed by the report instead?

Hope that's clear?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I display 'No data available.' when there are no rows to show on the report?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146944/how-do-i-display-no-data-available-when-there-are-no-rows-to-show-on-the-repo)

Answer (score 0):

You can try expression like:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!FieldName.Value, "Accounts are OK", Fields!FieldName.Value))
```

Or if you want to check if there is no data at all, you can try to throw an error in TSQL in following:

```
--add this line to the end of query:
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 RAISERROR('Accounts are OK', 16, 1)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response, but where would I I place the expression in SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Stored Procedure you can then insert your Select statement data into a table variable before returning it.  From this you can perform a check on its contents before it is returned to the report.

For example if you populate a table of data you wish to return as follows

```
INSERT INTO @ReturnTable (Account_Ref, ...)
SELECT  ir.SourceRef, ...
```

You can then query it's contents by using a command such as

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @ReturnTable) = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @ReturnTable (Account_Ref, ...)
    SELECT 'All Accounts are OK', ...
END
```

You can then perform a check within the report to see if the Account_Ref is 'All Accounts are OK', and if so display the report appropriately.  You can even set the entire report's contents inside a rectangle with the visibility set to the result of

```
=iif(First(Fields!Account_Ref.Value) = "All Accounts are OK", false, true)
```

You can layer another object (an information message perhaps) on top of this with the inverse of this visibility set.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This seems a bit complex to me as I have never used Stored Procedures.