# ssrs if - cannot print the requested value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have the following `iif`

> `IIF(LEN(Fields!IDENTITE.Value)=0,"Known manager","Unknown manager")`

Yet for some specific case, nothing is appearing (e.g. no known nor unknown)

I checked the results with a sql query and nothing is appearing (the result is below)

[image]

I amended my `iif` to reflect this case

> `IIF(COUNT(Fields!IDENTITE.Value)=0,"Known manager","Unknown manager")`

Yet the same issue is appearing

Any ideas on the why?

Thanks

Update : I tried the countrows as mentionned by @breez and I got this error

[image]

Comment: Since the sql query result has zero rows, have you tried the "CountRows" function in SSRS?

Comment: Hi @breez , should not the `count` do the same trick?

Comment: @breez I tried your advice and I have this error (see update on my question)

Comment: Is your expression in a table with Row Groups? If so try the `COUNT` expression in an item without grouping, like a standalone text box.

Comment: Hi @PeteRennard-Cumming, I did that (or did I do it correctly?) -_-'

Comment: Try adding a new Text Box item to the report, with just  `=COUNT(Fields!IDENTITE.Value)` as the expression in it. In 2008 R2, this still shows 0 even if the dataset has no rows. Does it do the same in 2012?

Comment: @PeteRennard-Cumming I'm using visual studio 2013. Nothing is appearing , no zero or 1 , just plain `""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible way to deal with the absence of rows is the following:

- Click on the tablix , look for **NoRowsMessage** option and type the text you want (example: **"No known managers"**)

Next time there are no rows, this message will be displayed

PS: It is only doable for matrix, list and tables not for textbox. For more info, click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146944/how-do-i-display-no-data-available-when-there-are-no-rows-to-show-on-the-repo)